# Prove equivalence of relations - Complex Analysis when there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f$ is differentiable on $D*(z_0; \delta)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Given the following statement there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f$ is differentiable on
$D*(z_0; \delta)$.

I have deduced here that:

$(i)$ ord$ (f; z0) = n$;

$(ii)$ there exist real numbers $\alpha, \beta > 0$ such that:

$\alpha|z - z_0|^n < |f(z)| < \beta|z -z_0|^n$

for $0 < |z - z_0| < \delta$.

Can someone help explain how these are equivalent?

Comment: What's the _definition_ of $ord$???

Answer (score 1):

I'll try and direct you in the correct way of proving this by pointing out the first few steps:

Allow the Laurent Series for $f$ at $z_0$ to be $\sum a_n(z-z_0)^n$

First, suppose ord $(f,z_0)=n$

Then, $(z-z_0)^{-n}f(z)=a_n+g(z)$, where $g(z) \rightarrow 0$ as $z \rightarrow z_0$

Given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that

$|g(z)|<\epsilon|a_n|$ whenever $0<|z-z_0|<\delta$

From here I hope you can continue.